# How to identify pivot chart on an excel worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, pivot-chart, vba

I'm creating an excel dashboard in which I've placed a pivot chart and I want to govern its visibility by the click of a checkbox. I'm not able to identify the pivot chart object on my worksheet and hence can't use the code I can do for any other activeX control like a label. e.g. i can find my label 'lblSales' in the sheet object but I can't find 'pivotChartRC' which is the name of my pivot chart Is there anyway I can do that?

```
Private Sub checkBoxRC_Click()

If (checkBoxResponseCurve.Value) Then

   Sheet1.lblSales.Visible = True
Else
   Sheet1.lblSales.Visible = False

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you already record a macro in which you just move the pivotchart around a bit? That should give you the ID of the pivotchart

Comment: @Luuklag No, I wasn't aware of this. Thanks!! That helped. New to Macros. Any pointers on how I could change the ID's of these objects. Right now I'd have to do something like Sheet1.Shapes("Chart 20") and so on..

Comment: You could declare the objects. Just google for declaring shape object.